# How to make loop out of these?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

How to make loop out of following HTML?

#### HTML

```html
<div class="dropdown-content" ng-repeat="cat in categoryList | orderBy: 'id'">
    <a ng-click="getProductsByCategory(1)"  ng-model="category.id">Cakes</a>
    <a ng-click="getProductsByCategory(2)"  ng-model="category.id">Pies</a>
    <a ng-click="getProductsByCategory(3)"  ng-model="category.id">Donuts</a>
    <a ng-click="getProductsByCategory(4)"  ng-model="category.id">Strudels and kishi</a>
    <a ng-click="getProductsByCategory(5)"  ng-model="category.id">Macaroons</a>
    <a ng-click="getProductsByCategory(6)"  ng-model="category.id">Cheesecakes</a>
    <a ng-click="getProductsByCategory(7)"  ng-model="category.id">Ice cream</a>
    <a ng-click="getProductsByCategory(8)"  ng-model="category.id">Assorti</a>
    <a ng-click="getProductsByCategory(9)"  ng-model="category.id">Low-calorie</a>
    <a ng-click="getProductsByCategory(10)"  ng-model="category.id">Guacamole</a>
    <a ng-click="getProductsByCategory(11)"  ng-model="category.id">Сroissants</a>
    <a ng-click="getProductsByCategory(12)"  ng-model="category.id">Sorbet</a>
    <a ng-click="getProductsByCategory(13)"  ng-model="category.id">Tiramisu</a>
    <a ng-click="getProductsByCategory(14)"  ng-model="category.id">Cookies</a>
    <a ng-click="getProductsByCategory(15)"  ng-model="category.id">Fruit and Puree</a>
</div>
```

#### What I tried

I tried JavaScript but I had problem with quotation marks:

```js
let i; for (i=1; i<=16; i++) { document.writeln("<a ng-click="getProductsByCategory('+i+')">category.name</a>"); }
```

Comment: You can use `ng-repeat` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood the point correctly. But if you want to generate the list automatically using JS you can use this loop:

```js
var arr = ['Cakes', 'Pies', 'Donuts', 'Strudels and kishi', 'Macaroons', 'Cheesecakes', 'Ice cream', 'Assorti', 'Low-calorie', 'Guacamole', 'Сroissants', 'Sorbet', 'Tiramisu', 'Cookies', 'Fruit and Puree'];

var res = '';
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    res += '<a ng-click="getProductsByCategory(' + (i + 1) + ')" ng-model="category.id">' + arr[i] + '</a> <br>';
}

var wrap = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content')[0];
wrap.innerHTML = res;
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-content" ng-repeat="cat in categoryList | orderBy: 'id'"></div>
```